# Why does my attempt to add and remove classes to an HTML-element only work one way?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Very basic task, don't worry about the coding style itself. I'm sure there are way more efficent and prettier ways of coding. The question is *why* the code doesn't work the way it is supposed to: It should add class "a" and remove class "b" and vice versa (depending on the class that is currently attached). It only works one way though, the class "closed" can be attached, but then "open" would not work anymore. Why is that?

HTML

```
<ul id="tasks">
    <li class="open">AAAAA</li>
    <li class="open">BBBBB</li>
    <li class="open">CCCCC</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.open {text-decoration: underline;}

.closed {text-decoration: line-through;}
```

JS

```
function doTask(event) {
    event.target.classList.remove("open");
    event.target.classList.add("closed");
}

function undoTask(event) {
    event.target.classList.remove("closed");
    event.target.classList.add("open");
}


function setup () {
    document.querySelectorAll("li.open")[0].addEventListener("click", doTask);
    document.querySelectorAll("li.open")[1].addEventListener("click", doTask);
    document.querySelectorAll("li.open")[2].addEventListener("click", doTask);
    document.querySelectorAll("li.closed")[0].addEventListener("click", undoTask);
    document.querySelectorAll("li.closed")[1].addEventListener("click", undoTask);
    document.querySelectorAll("li.closed")[2].addEventListener("click", undoTask);}

window.addEventListener("load", setup);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding event listeners to these elements in your `setup()` function:

```
document.querySelectorAll("li.closed")[0]
document.querySelectorAll("li.closed")[1]
document.querySelectorAll("li.closed")[2]
```

Those elements **do not exist** yet when you execute `setup()`. That's why when clicking on a `<li>` element with `class="closed"`, it won't work.

The solution is to check the class of that specific element after clicking it. Like so:

```js
function onLiClick(event) {
  if (event.target.className === 'open') event.target.className = 'closed';
  else event.target.className = 'open';
}

function setup() {
  for (var li of document.querySelectorAll('li')) li.addEventListener('click', onLiClick);
}

setup();
```

```css
.open::after {
  content: "open";
}

.closed::after {
  content: "closed";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this part of code

```
document.querySelectorAll("li.closed")[0].addEventListener("click", undoTask);
document.querySelectorAll("li.closed")[1].addEventListener("click", undoTask);
document.querySelectorAll("li.closed")[2].addEventListener("click", undoTask);
```

you are trying to add `click` function to `li.closed`, but there isn't any `li.closed` until you clicked it. You can create another function (`doSomething` in the example below) for checking the target class, then `doTask` or `undoTask` depends on the contained class, like this

```js
function doTask(event) {
    event.target.classList.remove("open");
    event.target.classList.add("closed");
}

function undoTask(event) {
    event.target.classList.remove("closed");
    event.target.classList.add("open");
}

function doSomething(event){
  if (event.target.classList.contains('open')){
    doTask(event);
  } else {
    undoTask(event);
  }
}

function setup () {
    document.querySelectorAll("li")[0].addEventListener("click", doSomething);
    document.querySelectorAll("li")[1].addEventListener("click", doSomething);
    document.querySelectorAll("li")[2].addEventListener("click", doSomething);
}

window.addEventListener("load", setup);
```

```css
.open {text-decoration: underline;}

.closed {text-decoration: line-through;}
```

```html
<ul id="tasks">
    <li class="open">AAAAA</li>
    <li class="open">BBBBB</li>
    <li class="open">CCCCC</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because for lines like this `document.querySelectorAll("li.closed")[0].addEventListener("click", undoTask);` . It is  trying to add event to elements which does not exist at all.

Infact you may not need a separate function to remove the class.

Use  [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) method to toggle the class

```js
function doTask(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle("closed");
}
function setup() {
  document.querySelectorAll("li")[0].addEventListener("click", doTask);
  document.querySelectorAll("li")[1].addEventListener("click", doTask);
  document.querySelectorAll("li")[2].addEventListener("click", doTask);
}
window.addEventListener("load", setup);
```

```css
.open {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
   .closed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tasks">
  <li class="open">AAAAA</li>
  <li class="open">BBBBB</li>
  <li class="open">CCCCC</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
function setup () {
    document.querySelectorAll("li.open")[0].addEventListener("click", doTask);
    document.querySelectorAll("li.open")[1].addEventListener("click", doTask);
    document.querySelectorAll("li.open")[2].addEventListener("click", doTask);
}

    function doTask(event) {
        if (!event.target.classList.contains("open")) {
            undoTask(event);
        } else {
                    event.target.classList.remove("open");
                event.target.classList.add("closed");    
        }
    }

    function undoTask(event) {
        event.target.classList.remove("closed");
        event.target.classList.add("open");
    }
```